# What was the final line in The Abominable Bride?

Tags: sherlock

My DVR let me down and it seems I'm not alone. So, how does this labyrinth end?

> The 19th century pair are discussing this fantastic story. Holmes says it's just extrapolation. "From a drop of water, the ocean."

Then what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A LiveJournal (apparently that's still a thing...) user called Ariane Devere has posted [a transcript of the special episode](http://arianedevere.livejournal.com/81842.html) which, based on my recollection, appears to be accurate (for the ending, at least, which is the only part I checked). You can read the relevant section below, if you wish, though I'd personally suggest finding a way to watch it.

Note: There does appear to be a little bit of personal opinion injected into the commentary of the action, particularly at the very end of the below quote.

> WATSON (offscreen): Flying machines; these, er, telephone contraptions ...
>   (The screen fades up to reveal Holmes and Watson sitting in their armchairs in the sitting room of 221B. Each of them is smoking a pipe.)
>   WATSON: What sort of lunatic fantasy is that?
>   HOLMES: It was simply my conjecture of what a future world might look like, and how you and I might fit inside it.
>   (Watson nods.)
>   HOLMES: From a drop of water, a logician should be able to infer the possibility of an Atlantic or a Niagara.
>   WATSON: Or a Reichenbach.
>   HOLMES: Have you written up your account of the case?
>   WATSON: Yes.
>   HOLMES: Hmm. Modified to put it down as one of my rare failures, of course?
>   WATSON: Of course.
>   (Holmes looks thoughtful for a moment.)
>   HOLMES: “The Adventure of ... the Invisible Army.”
>   (Watson looks upwards, considering it.)
>   HOLMES: “The League of Furies”? (He leans forward, smiling.) “The Monstrous Regiment.”
>   WATSON: I rather thought ... “The Abominable Bride.”
>   HOLMES (sitting back): A trifle lurid.
>   WATSON: It’ll sell. It’s got proper murders in it, too.
>   HOLMES (pointing his pipe at him): You’re the expert.
>   WATSON: As for your own tale, are you sure it’s still just a seven percent solution that you take? I think you may have increased the dosage.
>   HOLMES: Perhaps I was being a little fanciful ...
>   (He looks down thoughtfully.)
>   HOLMES: ... but perhaps such things could come to pass.
>   (He stands up.)
>   HOLMES: In any case, I know I would be very much at home in such a world.
>   (Watson chuckles as Holmes walks across the room towards the right-hand window.)
>   WATSON: Don’t think I would be.
>   HOLMES: I beg to differ.
>   (He looks out of the window.)
>   HOLMES: But then I’ve always known I was a man out of his time.
>   (He puts his pipe in his mouth and continues to look out of the window. The ‘Pursuit’ theme starts again, this time with a Victorian twist to it, as the camera slowly pulls back. Down in the street below, customers are going into SPEEDY’S Sandwich Bar & Cafe while more people – all dressed in modern-day clothing – walk past, and the road is busy with cars. A black cab passes a number 11 bus – destination Baker Street – as they drive past 221B ...
>   ... where it is always 1895.)

Comment: I believe I saw up to "a little fanciful ..."